# How can I preseed commands to run after the preseed reboot?

Tags: 12.04, preseed

During an automated preseed installation, how can I run a script just once *after* the final reboot?

My use case is provisioning a machine with [salt](http://www.saltstack.com/), as called by a [foreman](http://theforeman.org/).  Foreman gives me a opportunity to run an arbitrary script after an installation, which boils down to a `preseed/late_command`.

This is great, but I'm discovering that the preseed environment doesn't look quite like a normal boot (concretely `/var/run/utmp` appears to be missing), and this is confusing salt.  Rather than make piece-meal fixes to the preseed environment, it would be nice to just call the tool in a "real" boot, such as the one after the final preseed reboot.

I'm aware of hacks like adding something to `/etc/rc.local` (or similar) that cleans itself up after running.  Before I go down that road I want to know if there is a better option within the preseeding tool itself.

I'm targeting 12.04.

Comment: Have you tried prefixing the command you want run with `in-target` when you use it as a `late_command`?

Comment: Alas that is many years ago and in a different country.  I believe I did the `rc.local` hack.